# Pytorch optimizer makes loss values increase with time , takes non-optimal steps

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, loss-function, autograd

I’ve encountered some strange behavior in my model’s training outputs. It seems that the steps the optimizer takes do not help with convergence, and in many cases do the opposite of what the loss function would entail. For the sake of testing, I make all labels of the dataset 0.86 (arbitrary value) to see if the model can at least predict a constant value. Using the MSELoss here are the outputs at each training step :

```
             Loss                       |                 Model Output.              |  Label    

tensor(0.3838, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>) tensor([[0.2405]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.2788, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>) tensor([[0.3320]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.1464, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>) tensor([[0.4774]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.0539, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>) tensor([[0.6278]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.0121, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>) tensor([[0.7500]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.0006, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>) tensor([[0.8354]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.0009, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>) tensor([[0.8908]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.0043, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>) tensor([[0.9257]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.0077, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>) tensor([[0.9475]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.0104, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>) tensor([[0.9619]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.0124, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>) tensor([[0.9713]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.0138, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>) tensor([[0.9776]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.0149, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>) tensor([[0.9820]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
```

Here the steps the optimizer is taking is not conducive to lowering the loss, but instead moves in the direction of converging to 1.    The same thing also happens when changing the loss to L1Loss:

```
              Loss                    |                 Model Output.             |       Label    
tensor(0.8063, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>) tensor([[0.0537]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.7222, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>) tensor([[0.1378]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.5698, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>) tensor([[0.2902]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.3777, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>) tensor([[0.4823]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.1891, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>) tensor([[0.6709]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.0419, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>) tensor([[0.8181]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.0509, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>) tensor([[0.9109]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.0926, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>) tensor([[0.9526]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.1121, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>) tensor([[0.9721]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
tensor(0.1224, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>) tensor([[0.9824]], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>) tensor([[0.8600]])
```

my model is defined as follows :

```py
class DualBertForClassification(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, bert_model_a, bert_model_b):
        super(DualBertForClassification, self).__init__()
        
        self.bert_model_wt = bert_model_a
        self.bert_model_mutant = bert_model_b
        self.layer_1 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.layer_2 = nn.Linear(512, 128)
        self.layer_3 = nn.Linear(128, 16)
        self.layer_4 = nn.Linear(16, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x_a = x[0]  
        x_b = x[1]
        x = torch.cat(
            (
                self.bert_model_wt(**x_a).last_hidden_state, # [batch_sz,sequence_sz,1024]
                self.bert_model_mutant(**x_b).last_hidden_state 
            ), 
            1
        )  # [batch_sz, 2*sequence_sz, 1024, ]
        x = torch.tanh(self.layer_1(x)) # [batch_sz, 2*sequence_sz, 512, ]
        x = torch.tanh(self.layer_2(x)) # [batch_sz, 2*sequence_sz, 128, ]
        x = torch.tanh(self.layer_3(x)) # [batch_sz, 2*sequence_sz, 16, ]
        x = torch.tanh(self.layer_4(x)) # [batch_sz, 2*sequence_sz, 1, ]
        x = torch.mean(x, dim = 1)  # [batch_sz, 1]
        return x
```

bert_model_a , bert_model_b are both pretrained identical BERT models. Whose output sizes are shown in the comments. Here is also the training loop which produced the printed output shown above.

```py
    model1 = BertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
    model2 = BertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
    model = DualBertForClassification(model1, model2)

    
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.05, momentum=0.9)

    
    loss_fct = nn.L1Loss(reduction="sum") # also with nn.MSELoss(reduction="sum")
    model.train()
    for index, (input_a, input_b) in enumerate(zip(wt_inputs, alt_inputs)):
        label_val = torch.tensor([[0.86]], dtype = torch.float32)
        model_output = model((input_a, input_b))
        loss = loss_fct(model_output, label_val)
        print(loss, model_output, label_val)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
```

My thoughts are that this could be an issue with the way autograd is handling the two input BERT models, but I still cannot think of an explanation that could explain the growing loss over time. I've alsor played with changing the outputs of the model via different activation layers at the end of the `forward(x)` method. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: The optimizer acheived a lower error in 6 iterations, but then waffled. Can you induce early stopping by checking the loss and leaving when it goes below say 0.001?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved from the comment posted here:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/loss-function-s-not-reflecting-optimum-values-and-increasing-with-time/188492/2

It seems as though there isn’t anything super suspicious going on under the hood of loss computation, backprop etc. I tried all of the things you suggested:

- lower learning rate
- no gradient computation on the two BertModel instances
- using the same batch each step as input

And the model did in fact converge to 0.86 as expected. It looks like your comment about noise across batches was correct since using the same batch each time seemed to solve it. Also I ran the exact same configuration as described above but without freezing the weights of the BertModel, and again it seems to converge at 0.86 predictions, so it doesn’t seem like there is anything unusual about those components either.